# How to set errors pages when user try to access asset directory without specify file name in Codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my directories of my Javacript folder

Index of /my_project/project_name/path(to javascript library)/assets/js

**1, Parent Directory customize.min.js**

**2, docs.min.js**

**3, ie-emulation-modes-warning.js**

**4, ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js**

**5, ie8-responsive-file-warning.js**

**6, raw-files.min.js src/ vendor/**

Here is directories of CSS folder

**1, Parent Directory**

**2, bootstrap-theme.css**

**3, bootstrap-theme.css.map**

**4, bootstrap-theme.min.css**

**5, bootstrap.css**

**6, bootstrap.css.map**

**7, bootstrap.min.css**

**8, datepicker.css**

**10, style.css**

Here is .HTACCESS

```
# Set PHP Time Zone:
#SetEnv TZ America/New_York
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Option +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kim/resturan/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|pages|video|images|social|style|sliderengine|bar|robots\.text)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

How can I write some link for it

And It is also can access to all director of asset if user type url as they know.

**I don't understand how to configure in .HTACCESS or How can I do with controller function in Codeigniter to control all that asset folder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one new htaccess file with the following line and put it in you assets folder. it will display "Access forbidden!" message to user if anyone access directly in browser.

```
Options -Indexes
```

We can restrict to view a files but those assets will not display in website too. `so don't try this.`it is only needed for your private files in your server as not being used for your website.

```
deny from all
```

If you want to redirect to specific page in case anyone accessing your assets directory. use the following options

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://yoursite.com/403_page
```

Comment: Now I copy .htaccess and put 

Deny from all

and I get Forbidden so how can I I access to file in this folder

Comment: I said, dont use "deny from all" because you can not access from browser at any time. So means, Only restrict directory and don't do for files.

Comment: How to write conditional in .htaccess to restrict file

Comment: @Asik  i Have a Doubt can we use .htaccess so that programs are accessible only within the request from my server and if any user tries to mimic it by sending through any other media should be restricted, if possible how to achieve this

Comment: so you want to load the resource only the request come from your domain? if yes, I dont know that how to achieve this :) check the apache htaccess docs..

Comment: you are exactly right that is the behavior i need , i will give apache htaccess docs a try